# Group rows based upon a pattern change in specific columns in SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I have data stored in a table say T1. I want to group rows such that data in specific rows changes its value and have rows **before** and **after** the change in the data pattern. For example,

Table T1:

```
ID    Operation    Worker

1         1           A
2         1           A
3         2           A
4         2           A
5         1           A
6         1           A
7         1           A
```

How do I get rows ID before and after the change such as IDs 2,3,4,5?

Edit: I have use SQL Server 2008 R2 so lag, lead functions are not available.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this.

```
DECLARE @T1 TABLE(ID INT, Operation INT,   Worker VARCHAR(5))
INSERT INTO @T1 VALUES
(1 ,1 ,'A'),
(2 ,1 ,'A'),
(3 ,2 ,'A'),
(4 ,2 ,'A'),
(5 ,1 ,'A'),
(6 ,1 ,'A'),
(7 ,1 ,'A')


;WITH T AS (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER()OVER(ORDER BY ID) AS RN FROM @T1)
SELECT T.ID
     FROM T 
    LEFT JOIN T AS TP ON T.RN = TP.RN + 1
    LEFT JOIN T AS TN ON T.RN = TN.RN - 1
WHERE 
    T.Operation <> TP.Operation 
        OR T.Operation <> TN.Operation
```

Result:

```
ID
-----------
2
3
4
5
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need `lead()` & `lag()` :

```
select t.*
from (select t.*, 
             lag(operation, 1, operation) over (partition by worker order by id) as prev_op,
             lead(operation, 1, operation) over (partition by worker order by id) as next_op
      from tabke t
     ) t
where (operation <> prev_op) or (operation <> next_op);
```

EDIT : For older version you can use `apply` :

```
select t.*
from table t outer apply
     ( select top (1) prev_op.*
       from table prev_op
       where prev_op.id < t.id
       order by prev_op.id desc
     ) prev_op outer apply
     ( select top (1) next_op.*
       from table next_op
       where next_op.id > t.id
       order by prev_op.id asc
     ) next_op
where (t.operation <> prev_op.operation) or (t.operation <> next_op.operation);
```

Comment: I wish but SQL 2008 R2 does not have these functions.

Answer (score 0):

This is painful without `lead()` and `lag()`.  So, let's add them using `cross apply`:

```
select t.*,
from t outer apply
     (select top (1) tprev.*
      from t tprev
      where tprev.id < t.id
      order by tprev.id desc
     ) tprev outer apply
     (select top (1) tnext.*
      from t tnext
      where tnext.id > t.id
      order by tnext.id asc
     ) tnext
where t.operation = 2 or
      (tprev.operation = 2 or tprev.operation is null) or
      (tnext.operation = 2 or tnext.operation is null)
```